# How to re-initialize rails-ujs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, navigation-drawer, mdc, rails-ujs

I have a view within my Rails app which includes a link:

```
= link_to 'abc', abc_url, remote: true
```

This link on its own works as intended.

But I embedded it in the [drawer component](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-drawer#temporary-drawer-usage) of the [mdc library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web).
Now the link appears to be working like a regular link.

Is there a way to re-initialize [rails-ujs](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts) after the drawer got opened? Or to circumvent the problem?